# EF Core "No DbContext named xxx was found'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have multiple contexts and one of them works, but the other three cannot be found.

I'm using `PM> Add-Migration InitialCreateLdapIdentity -context LdapIdentityDbContext<LdapUser, LdapUserRole> -verbose`

This is what it outputs:

```
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider...
Finding BuildWebHost method...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from BuildWebHost method on 'Program'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
  User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\brech\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Found DbContext 'ApplicationIdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole>'.
Found DbContext 'LdapIdentityDbContext<LdapUser, LdapUserRole>'.
Found DbContext 'BlogIdentityDbContext<BlogUser, BlogUserRole>'.
Found DbContext 'CountriesDbContext'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: No DbContext named 'LdapIdentityDbContext<LdapUser, LdapUserRole>' was found.
```

The funny thing is when I run `Add-Migration InitialCreateCountries -context CountriesDbContext` then this works.

I also tried without the generic parameters `Add-Migration InitialCreateLdapIdentity -context LdapIdentityDbContext` but to no avail.

My `Startup.cs` contains this:

```
services
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationIdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole>>(
                options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Identity"));
                })
        .AddDbContext<LdapIdentityDbContext<LdapUser, LdapUserRole>>(
                options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LdapIdentity"));
                })
        .AddDbContext<BlogIdentityDbContext<BlogUser, BlogUserRole>>(
                options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BlogIdentity"));
                })
        .AddDbContext<CountriesDbContext>(
                options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Countries"));
                });

services
        .AddApplicationIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationIdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole>>()
        .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>>()
        .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole>>()
        .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole>>()
        .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole>>()
        .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole>>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services
        .AddLdapIdentity<LdapUser, LdapUserRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<LdapIdentityDbContext<LdapUser, LdapUserRole>>()
        .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<LdapUser>>()
        .AddUserStore<LdapUserWtore<LdapUser, LdapUserRole>>()
        .AddSignInManager<LdapSignInManager<LdapUser, LdapUserRole>>()
        .AddUserManager<LdapUserManager<LdapUser, LdapUserRole>>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services
        .AddBlogIdentity<BlogUser, BlogUserRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<BlogIdentityDbContext<BlogUser, BlogUserRole>>()
        .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<BlogUser>>()
        .AddUserStore<BlogUserStore<BlogUser, BlogUserRole>>()
        .AddUserManager<BlogUserManager<BlogUser, BlogUserRole>>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I'm all out of ideas, especially because in the verbose log it says explicitly that it found the contexts.

Anyone has any ideas?

*edit*

The methods `AddApplicationIdentity<…>`, `AddLdapIdentity<…>` and `AddBlogIdentity<…>` are extension methods on `ServiceCollection` and I have peeked at the asp.net core implementation on [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)

So my implementation looks like this:

```
public static IdentityBuilder AddApplicationIdentity<TUser, TUserRole>(
        this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction = null)
        where TUser : ApplicationUser, new()
        where TUserRole : ApplicationUserRole
    {
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IRoleValidator<TUserRole>, RoleValidator<TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ApplicationUserStore<TUser, TUserRole>, ApplicationUserStore<TUser, TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ApplicationIdentityDbContext<Identity.Models.ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole>, ApplicationIdentityDbContext<Identity.Models.ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ApplicationUserManager<TUser, TUserRole>, ApplicationUserManager<TUser, TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ApplicationSignInManager<TUser, TUserRole>, ApplicationSignInManager<TUser, TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<RoleManager<TUserRole>, AspNetRoleManager<TUserRole>>();

        if (setupAction != null)
        {
            services.Configure(setupAction);
        }

        return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), typeof(TUserRole), services);
    }

    public static IdentityBuilder AddLdapIdentity<TUser, TUserRole>(
        this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction = null)
        where TUser : LdapUser, new()
        where TUserRole : LdapUserRole
    {
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IRoleValidator<TUserRole>, RoleValidator<TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<LdapUserStore<TUser, TUserRole>, LdapUserStore<TUser, TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<LdapIdentityDbContext<TUser, TUserRole>, LdapIdentityDbContext<TUser, TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<LdapUserManager<TUser, TUserRole>, LdapUserManager<TUser, TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<LdapSignInManager<TUser, TUserRole>, LdapSignInManager<TUser, TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<RoleManager<TUserRole>, AspNetRoleManager<TUserRole>>();

        if (setupAction != null)
        {
            services.Configure(setupAction);
        }

        return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), typeof(TUserRole), services);
    }

    public static IdentityBuilder AddBlogIdentity<TUser, TUserRole>(
        this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction = null)
        where TUser : BlogUser, new()
        where TUserRole : BlogUserRole
    {
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IRoleValidator<TUserRole>, RoleValidator<TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<BlogUserStore<TUser, TUserRole>, BlogUserStore<TUser, TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<BlogIdentityDbContext<BlogUser, BlogUserRole>, BlogIdentityDbContext<BlogUser, BlogUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<BlogUserManager<TUser, TUserRole>, BlogUserManager<TUser, TUserRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<RoleManager<TUserRole>, AspNetRoleManager<TUserRole>>();

        if (setupAction != null)
        {
            services.Configure(setupAction);
        }

        return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), typeof(TUserRole), services);
    }
}
```

The implementation of `LdapIdentityDbContext` is this:

```
public class LdapIdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole> : IdentityDbContext<TUser, TUserRole, Guid>
    where TUser : LdapUser
    where TRole : LdapUserRole
{
    public LdapIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<LdapIdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole>> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are already adding `LdapIdentityDbContext`, `BlogIdentityDbContext`, and `ApplicationIdentityDbContext` using `AddDbContext`, you don't need to add their scoped versions in your extension methods (the dbContexts are added as transient).

Comment: That didn't do it, before I had my problems, I had and Identity db from another project, and everything worked, but I changed my connection string so that I had separate db's and when I wanted to create migrations for those separate contexts the problems started, so I highly doubt that that is the problem, but thanks anyway, I will remove that. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it, turns out you cannot use type parameters in the IdentityDbContext.